# Java Android stringToList: undefined type - guava

Tags: android, string, list, undefined, guava

I am working on Android SDK-NDK and have a problem with the following piece of code:

```
            case ColorArray:
                List<Color> lIdList = stringToList
                (   new Function<String, Color>() 
                    {
                        public Color apply(String pSubValue) 
                        {   return new Color(pSubValue);
                        }
                    }, 
                    lValue
                );
                break;
```

This is the message on FC16 that Eclipse IDE gives:

```
The method stringToList(new Function<String,Color>(){}, String) is undefined for the type StoreActivity
```

To solve it, I have included:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

I have also added 'guava-11.0.1.jar' in Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries.

But the problem doesn't go away.

All comments and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `StoreActivity` doesn't have `stringToList` method defined with this signature (`stringToList(new Function<String,Color>(){}, String)`), does it?

Comment: I don't even know where you'd expect that function to be coming from, OP.

Answer (score 2):

@Xaerxess and Louis Wasserman

You are right. The method definition is what was missing to get the code running. In the sequence is the stringToList Method defined:

```
private <TType> List<TType> stringToList(
                Function<String, TType> pConversion,
                String pValue) {
    String[] lSplitArray = pValue.split(";");
    List<String> lSplitList = Arrays.asList(lSplitArray);
    return Lists.transform(lSplitList, pConversion);
}
```

It solved the problem. Thanks for the valuable comments and remarks.

Comment: Wow. The Hungarian Notation is so unreadable :/ I'm glad we got rid of it thanks to our type systems and IDEs.